# Evaluate $\iint_s F\cdot n \,ds$ without using the divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

> Evaluate $\iint_s F\cdot n \,ds$ without using the divergence theorem
>   given $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ and S is the surface of the solid $W$, where
>   $W=\{{(x,y,z)\in R^3 | x^2+y^2\le 1 \,and\, x^2+y^2+z^2\le4}$}, with
>   the normal vector $n$ exterior.

Ans: $4\pi(8-3\sqrt 3 )$

Well, I'm kind lost in here. I think I have to separate the solid in 3 surfaces, but I don't know what else.

Comment: The surface has 3 pieces : a piece of cylinder and two pieces of spheres, so you can parametrize it and write an expression for $n$

Comment: You are correct that there are three pieces to $S$: the surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, $|z|\le\sqrt3$, and the top and bottom caps of the sphere, $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, $|z|\ge\sqrt3$. Both are oriented with the unit normal pointing *away* from the origin.

Comment: Yes, I know. I found the parametrization of the cylinder and the sphere. But when I found the flux of the vector field to the surface of the cylinder it gaves me zero and I freaked out thinking the other one will be zero as well because of the symmetry. Or it won't?

Comment: On the spherical pieces $(x,y,z) . n = 2$

Comment: It's always better not to freak too quickly. But you shouldn't have gotten $0$ for the flux outward across the cylinder, since the vector field points radially outward everywhere. You should actually be able to do the flux across the cylinder without doing any integrals at all! :)

Comment: @reuns: Most likely you're not telling the OP anything he doesn't know, and it's annoying that you don't think things through more before writing.

Comment: After you corrected your error, I removed my statement that you were wrong. But why not compose something carefully before you type?

Comment: Parametrization of the cylinder I have: $\alpha(\theta,z)=(cos(\theta),sin(\theta),z)$. So, $\iint_s1 (cos(\theta),sin(\theta),z)\cdot (cos(\theta),-sin(\theta),0)=\iint_s1 cos(\theta)^2-sin(\theta)^2 \,dz\,d\theta$. With $-\sqrt 3 \le z \le \sqrt 3$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi.$

Comment: the minus sign isn't there, so it is $\cos(\theta)^2+\sin(\theta)^2$

Comment: $(cos(θ),−sin(θ),0)$ is the cross product N.

Comment: @reuns did you do the derivation?

Comment: Gustavo, review the signs in your formula for cross product. This is very important. PLUS, you should should see from the geometry that the normal vector to the cylinder at $(x,y,z)$ is $(x,y,0)$. Draw pictures!!!

Comment: I saw the mistake hahah. Thanks.

Comment: Not really. The sum of the surface of the top and the surface of the cylinder arrived to the result, but the bottom is not zero.

Comment: I did wrong something here, I don't know what.